# Unicode characters in ColdFusion CLIENT scope

Tags: unicode, utf-8, coldfusion

Is it possible to store unicode (utf-8) characters in ColdFusion's CLIENT scope? (CF9)

If I set a CLIENT scope variable and dump it immediately, it looks fine. But on next page load (ie: when CLIENT scope read back from storage) I just see question marks for the unicode characters.

I'm using a database for persistence and the data column in the CDATA table has been set to ntext.

Looking directly in the database I can see that the records have not been written correctly (again, just question marks showing for unicode characters).

Comment: You might need to set `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8" />` in both the page you set it and the page you try and output it

Comment: Thanks Duncan. Just tried that now, but it had no effect.

Comment: Have you checked the: String format "Enable High Ascii characters and Unicode ..." option in your client DSN?

Comment: Great - that's sorted it. Thanks Leigh!

Comment: If you move your comment to an answer I can mark as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From the comments)

Have you checked/enabled the: **String format** --Enable High Ascii characters and Unicode ..." option in your client datasource?

From [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fe5.html):

> Enable this option if your application uses Unicode data in
>   DBMS-specific Unicode data types, such as National Character or nchar.